# How to retrive clob data from oracle collection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a requirment where oracle procedure is sending me a  oracle collection. This collection contains clob data type.
How do I get this clob data ?

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
            DBLayer db=new DBLayer();
            CallableStatement ftRPCaStmt = null;
            ResultSet requestPropCursor = null;
            CallableStatement callsmt=null;
            String dataCol="stg_core.tab_inft_flexi_gl_rec_hd2";
            Connection conn=db.getConnection();
    ArrayDescriptor structDescriptor1 = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor   (dataCol.toUpperCase(), conn);                   
                  ftRPCaStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call stg_core.gl_test1_clob_c2(?,?,?) }");
            ftRPCaStmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
            ftRPCaStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            ftRPCaStmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY,dataCol.toUpperCase());
            ftRPCaStmt.execute();

            Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) ftRPCaStmt.getObject(3)).getArray();
```

when I printed data I'm getting data value as `Ljava.lang.Object;@b2fd8f`, but I need the clob data..
Please suggest..

Answer (score 1):

Try as

`callsmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CLOB);`

and then

```
Clob  clob = proc_stmt.getClob(3);
Reader reader = clob .getCharacterStream();
            char[] buffer = new char[1];
            while(reader.read(buffer) > 0) {
                log.info(buffer);
            }           
//          log.info(retValue);
            ....
```

the above code snippet is not compiled, this is to provide the guideline.

Comment: @polpan i am getting below error when tried your suggestion.Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GL_TEST1_CLOB_C2'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: @user2500313 Add `stg_core.gl_test1_clob_c2` function's signature by editing your question.